# Python Pandas: Convert Date to Text e.g. Aug 2018 --> 08-2018 or 01-08-2018

Tags: python, pandas

Convert Date e.g. Aug 2018 --> 01-08-2018 ??

Here's my sample input

```
id      year_pass
1       Aug 2018 - Nov 2018
2       Jul 2017 - Oct 2017
```

Output should be:

```
id      year_pass
1       01-08-2018
2       01-07-2017
```

OR

```
id      year_start    year_end
1       01-08-2018    01-11-2018
2       01-07-2018    01-10-2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# creating the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.57, 'Aug 2018 - Nov 2018'], 
                   [0.11, 'Jul 2017 - Oct 2017']], 
                   columns=['id', 'year_pass'])

# splitting the date column on the '-'
year_start, year_end = df['year_pass'].str.split('-')
df.drop('year_pass', axis=1, inplace=True)

# assigning the split values to columns
df['year_start'] = year_start
df['year_end'] = year_end

# converting to datetime objects
df['year_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_start'])
df['year_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_end'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the year_pass column like this:

```
new_df = df.year_pass.str.split(' - ')

new_df1 = new_df.apply(pd.Series)

new_df2 = pd.to_datetime(new_df1[0])
```

Then you can merge the resultant dataframe to the actual dataframe.
To put it in one line of code:

```
new_df = pd.to_datetime(df.year_pass.str.split(' - ').apply(pd.Series)[0])
```

The date format would be YYYY-MM-DD and not DD-MM-YYYY